# T-SQL Create Indicator Based on Ranges

Tags: t-sql, recursion, subquery

I have a table that is setup three columns:

```
EventName    |    StartDate    |    EndDate
FunRun            1/1/2018          1/10/2018
DumbRun           2/1/2018          2/5/2018
```

I have a separate dates table that has every date in the year with approximately 100 different attributes.

```
CalendarDate |    DayOfWeek    |    WeekendInd    |    etc...
1/1/2018          Sunday            1
1/2/2018          Monday            0
1/15/2018         Wednesday         0
```

I want to join the two tables to create an indicator if the calendar date is between the dates on the even table.

```
CalendarDate |    DayOfWeek    |    WeekendInd    |    EventInd
1/1/2018          Sunday            1                  1
1/2/2018          Monday            0                  1
1/15/2018         Wednesday         0                  0
```

I cannot seem to use a recursive CTE in a subquery. This table is already joined to 5 other subqueries. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question, you don't need recursion, just join 2 tables

```
select
    CalendarDate, DayOfWeek, WeekendInd, EventInd = isnull(EventInd, 0)
from
    CalendarTable a
    outer apply (
        select
            distinct EventInd = 1
        from
            EventsTable b
        where
            a.CalendarDate between b.StartDate and b.EndDate
    ) q
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Thanks!